# application insights unqiue requests

Tags: azure-application-insights

We have a REST API implemented as a Cloud Service, that sends telemetry to Application Insights. And we use commands like

- POST /api/groups/GRP_75e0b852-ee21-45fb-b943-13aa465c62da/members.
- POST /api/groups/GRP_75e0b852-ee21-45fb-b943-13aa465c62da/folders/FLD_080af364-ad37-4351-837e-4fb1d5f02e50/discussions

The sections of the command preceded by GRP_ and FLD_ are parameters.
This makes looking at the breakdown of requests in Application Insights difficult since those requests show up individually.

I’ve implemented an ITelemetryInitializer that “normalizes” the Context.Operation.Name (and the Request URL) in our requests. But I see that those request are showing up bucketed as “Other Values”.

[Requests with Other Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guw7r.png)

Is there any way to reset the "bucketing" of the top-level list, or do I need to get a new AppInsights instance?

Comment: Would it help you to just add custom events and track those? Or would that clutter up your entire application wiht custom events?

Comment: There seems to be a bunch of built-in goodness (Overview timeline Tile, etc...) that buckets with Operation Name, that I can't seem to reproduce reliably with filters and searches. So I'm trying to massage my data, if I'm wrong and we can get the same kind of reporting from custom events and/or metrics I'm willing to give that a shot.

Comment: We have have some similar URLs in our ASP.NET MVC app, where the "key" is in the middle of the URL, and AppInsights seems to do the expected thing.  It actually uses the MVC controller/action as the "request name."  We do have specific routes defined to reach this controller, so maybe that is how AI picks up the alternate name for the request? (Although it does NOT use the custom route name as I would have expected, just uses the ControllerName/ActionName)

Answer (score 1):

Standard dimentions like request name should be reset after a week. So if you stopped collecting parameters in the names it should clear up after a week. Current limit is 1000.